# Mountain Lion Notification Center. How system determines which application to launch?

Tags: macos, notifications

I've got a following problem:

I have 2 versions of my application installed on OS X 10.8
The new version has support of notification center and may create notification.

If both apps are not launched and I click on notification, created by the new version, old version of application starts.

1. How system determines, what to launch on notification click?
2. Should I do something to force OS X to "refresh" information about what to launch on notification click?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How system determines, what to launch on notification click?

The application that is launched is handled by [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH201-TP1).

> 1. Should I do something to force OS X to "refresh" information about what to launch on notification click?

If the newer application has a higher version in its Info.plist, by default this is the app that would be launched.

As the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-SW10) states in "Preferred Application for a URL": -

> If two or more versions of the same application have been found, give preference to the one with the latest version number.